# Finding $dy/dx$ from $ y^2 = \sin^4{2x} + \cos^4{2x} $ using implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Problem:

> Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ by implicit differentation for the following:
> $$ y^2 = \sin^4{2x} + \cos^4{2x} $$

Answer:
\begin{align*}
2y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 4(2) \sin^3(2x) \cos(2x) - 4(2) \cos^3(2x) \sin(2x) \tag1\\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 4  ( \sin^3(2x) \cos(2x) -  \cos^3(2x) \sin(2x) ) \tag2\\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 4 ( \sin(2x)\cos(2x)) ( \sin^2(2x) \cos(2x) -  \cos^2(2x) \sin(2x) ) \tag3\\
\\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 2 ( \sin(4x)) ( \sin(2x) \sin(2x) \cos(2x) -  \cos(2x) \cos(2x) \sin(2x) ) \tag4\\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 2 ( \sin(4x)) ( \sin(2x) \left( \frac{ \sin(4x)}{2 }\right)  -  \cos(2x) \left(  \frac{ \sin(4x)}{2 } \right) ) \tag5\\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= ( \sin(4x)) ( \sin(2x) \left( \sin(4x)\right)  -  \cos(2x) \sin(4x) ) \tag6\\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= ( \sin^2(4x)) ( \sin(2x)   -  \cos(2x) ) \tag7
\end{align*}
Hence my answer is:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{  ( \sin^2(4x)) ( \sin(2x)   -  \cos(2x) )   } { y } \tag{$\star$}$$

The book's answer is: $\frac{-\sin{8x}}{y} $
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: With this huge calculation, mistakes are bound to happen. It's better to use $\sin^4(2x)+\cos^4(2x)=(\sin^2(2x)+\cos^2(2x))^2-2\sin^2(2x)\cos^2(2x)$ and trigonometric identities for double angles.. (if you know them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is at the $3^{rd}$ step, where you are not extracting the common factor correctly.
\begin{align*}
2y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 4(2) \sin^3(2x) \cos(2x) - 4(2) \cos^3(2x) \sin(2x) \\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 4  ( \sin^3(2x) \cos(2x) -  \cos^3(2x) \sin(2x) ) \\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= 4 ( \sin(2x)\cos(2x)) ( \sin^2(2x) -  \cos^2(2x)  ) \\
y \frac{dy}{dx} &= -2\sin(4x) \cos(4x) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{-\sin(8x)}{y} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: I am thinking that the line $y \frac{dy}{dx} = 2\sin(4x)\cos(4x)$ should be $y \frac{dy}{dx} = -2\sin(4x)\cos(4x)$ because the formula for $\cos( 2 \theta) = \cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)$. You will notice in the line before it, we have: $\sin^2(2x) - \cos^2(2x)$. Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Simplify first with $2\sin^2t=1-\cos2t$ and $2\cos^2t=1+\cos 2t$

$$y^2=\sin^4{2x} + \cos^4{2x} = \frac34 +\frac14\cos8x$$

Then, differentiate implicitly

$$2yy’=- 2\sin8x\implies y’= -\frac{\sin8x}y$$